# Asking user for input - prime number code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
num = 3    #take input from the user
if num > 1: # if input is greater than 1 check for factors
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
               print(num,"is not a prime number")
               break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")
            #if input number is less than or equal to 1, it is not prime

else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

I have my code here which works out the prime number of the num section, what I need to do it ask the user for the input when I run the code.

Comment: Did you do any searching at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
num = int(input("Input a number: "))
```

Comment: No need for the `int()` unless you want to handle errors

Comment: @Saksow, the OPs code is clearly in Python 3.x

Comment: @Saksow That depends on the Python version. Casting it to an int will make it work in Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes I was using Python 2.x, thanks

Comment: Python 2 `input()` evaluates the user input as an expression, `raw_input()` returns a string. Python 3 `input()` returns a string no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Since `input()` always assumes that it's taking a string ,you have to convert it to `int` :

```
print("Enter a number:")
num = int(input())   #this here
if num > 1: # if input is greater than 1 check for factors
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
               print(num,"is not a prime number")
               break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")
            #if input number is less than or equal to 1, it is not prime

else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```